# How the Input Image Pixel Values Scaled in YOLO-V4?

Tags: image-processing, yolo, image-scaling, darknet, image-preprocessing

I have an issue with something vague for me regarding the input data preprocessing in YOLO-V4,
If the input image is a grayscale image of 16-bits per pixel, i.e. range of pixel values [0,2^16) instead of [0,2^8), it is mentioned that they are scaled so I want to ask about:

1- These values are scaled to be within -1 to 1 or 0 to 1?
2- Which method is used in scaling (where can I find its piece of code)?
3- Is the scaling done using the max value per image or the max depth per image, i.e in my case does the max used in the scaling will be 2^16 or the maximum value in the image for example 2000 or whatever?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

(1) - from 0 to 1.
Now scaling works as v = pix / 255.
[Here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/include/yolo_v2_class.hpp#L156)